# Proof of Quicksort's average time complexity

Tags: summation

I have been trying to understand average time complexity of quicksort by going through this [link](http://ki.pwr.edu.pl/cichon/Math/QSortAvg.pdf)

But I am not able to understand the step where 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} Q_k = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} Q_{n-1-k} $$

How are these two equal?

Comment: This is just change of variable. You're summing over $Q_0, Q_1, \dots, Q_{n-1}$ in the first sum, and $Q_{n-1}, Q_{n-2}, \dots, Q_1, Q_0$ in the second.

Comment: ohh.. thanks :)